OpenVPN and Stunnel Configure firewall on LAN
I currently have OpenVPN and Stunnel both working on my Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS which is running in virtualised Proxmox environment with ethernet passthrough.  My OpenVPN runs on TCP port 1443 with Stunnel on TCP port 443, with the OpenVPN DNS connected to my Pihole. My OpenVPN server runs on 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, with the ip address 192.168.1.124, and the subnet of OpenVPN is 10.8.0.0/24.
I have tried multiple methods of configuring a firewall using UFW and IPtables for routing my OpenVPN internet.  I would like to fully block my LAN network (such as 192.168.1.150) to prevent my clients accessing my home's network, but also allow vital internet ports such as DNS to be unblocked for the functioning of the vpn. Below is my Iptables and UFW configuration:
Iptables:
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 621 packets, 46979 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
44 12691 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      ens18   10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0

UFW:
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 1443/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 192.168.1.123              DENY IN     10.8.0.0/24
[ 4] 192.168.1.150              DENY OUT    10.8.0.0/24                (out)
[ 5] 10.8.0.0/24                REJECT IN   192.168.1.150
[ 6] 192.168.1.127              DENY OUT    10.8.0.0/24                (out)
[ 7] 192.168.1.123              DENY OUT    10.8.0.0/24                (out)
[ 8] 192.168.1.150 8006         DENY IN     10.8.0.0/24

Below are my OpenVPN server and client configurations:
OpenVPN Server:
port 1443
proto tcp
dev tun
tun-mtu 1320
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.127"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
management 127.0.0.1 5555
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_qs2L2DYUaw22IfhA.crt
key server_qs2L2DYUaw22IfhA.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3

OpenVPN Client:
client
proto tcp-client
remote 127.0.0.1 1443
dev tun
tun-mtu 1320
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_qs2L2DYUaw22IfhA name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-256-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>

When connected to the VPN client, I am still able to access ip addresses such as 192.168.1.150.  Is this due to a different subnet?
Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

I am not seeing anything in your firewall configuration that deny the IP/L3 forwarded ("route(d)" in ufw's term) traffics that you want to forbid. Also, the nat table (which is what you've shown for iptables) is irrelevant to the concern here. What relevant is the FORWARD chain in the filter table. Besides, better use/show iptables-save instead.
